# Cell Search in Pyhton

Tags: python, regex

I have a code that searches for words through `+` found in different cells
`(bio, username, name)`
But it doesn't work perfectly.
How can I make it so that when searching for words, it finds like this

For example, let's take the words

`Web3 + Founder`

And if both of these words occur either in both bio
Or one in bio one in username

In general, both words should be in these places

I'm currently using cycles.
Is it possible to somehow make them work through `RegEx`

`[(1161769, 1108822894, -1001568851464, 'Founder', 'None', 'Web3'),]` - `True`

`[(1161769, 1108822894, -1001568851464, 'Founder', 'None', 'None'),]` - `False`

`[(1161769, 1108822894, -1001568851464, 'Founder Web3', 'None', 'None'),]` - `True`

`[(1161769, 1108822894, -1001568851464, 'None', 'None', 'Web3 Founder'),]` - `True`

`[(1161769, 1108822894, -1001568851464, 'Founder', 'Founder', 'Web3'),]` - `True`

```
data = []
for i in rows:
    data.append(i)
clear_data = []
dict = {}

inp = input("Введите слова через '+': ").replace(' ', '').split('+')
lens = len(inp)
n = 0
for i in data:
    for j in i:
        for o in inp:
            if o.lower() in str(j).lower():
                n += 1

        if n >= lens:
            clear_data.append(i)
            n = 0
        else:
            n = 0
cnt = 0
for i in clear_data:
    cnt += 1
    print(cnt,i)
```

My algorithm doesn't always give me what I want

I think I was able to explain my problem to you

I need it to find two or more words, but at the same time all these `n` words were in these 3 cells at least in different places

Answer (score 1):

Given your input, you can just do all the work in a single list comprehension which checks if "founder" or "web3" is found in the strings in the last three elements of your tuples, no need for regex (althought equivalent regex would be `r"(?i)founder|web3"`).

```py
lines = [
    [(1161769, 1108822894, -1001568851464, "Founder", "None", "Web3")],
    [(1161769, 1108822894, -1001568851464, "Founder", "None", "None")],
    [(1161769, 1108822894, -1001568851464, "Founder Web3", "None", "None")],
    [(1161769, 1108822894, -1001568851464, "None", "None", "Web3 Founder")],
    [(1161769, 1108822894, -1001568851464, "Founder", "Founder", "Web3")],
]

web3_founder_lines = [
    line
    for line in lines
    if any("founder" in v.lower() for v in line[0][-3:])
    and any("web3" in v.lower() for v in line[0][-3:])
]
# contains
# [[(1161769, 1108822894, -1001568851464, 'Founder', 'None', 'Web3')],
#  [(1161769, 1108822894, -1001568851464, 'Founder Web3', 'None', 'None')],
#  [(1161769, 1108822894, -1001568851464, 'None', 'None', 'Web3 Founder')],
#  [(1161769, 1108822894, -1001568851464, 'Founder', 'Founder', 'Web3')]]
```